# PhantomJS: place div element on bottom part of a page

Tags: css, phantomjs, jsreport

I am using **jsreport** with **PhantomJS** for making reports for bills/invoices.
I need to place a div element on the bottom part of some pages. It is the part of a bill that the cashier of a bank can cut with a scissor.

I tried different ways with **CSS** to do it but when **jsreport** renders, the result is not what I expect.

These two examples show what I need:

One page:

[image: One page]

Two pages:

[image: Two pages]

I made a very basic example here if someone wants to edit it:
https://playground.jsreport.net/studio/workspace/rJRuPJkfW/57

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The javascript based solution:

You can find out the full height of the single page. You can also find out the real height of the document. These two values helps you to calculate the bottom of the last page. Then you can absolute position the cut area to the last page using js.

```
<script>
    // magical page size number was only estimated based on very long pdf
    // it differs based on the recipe and platform used to render
    // windows phantomjs 1.9.8 = 1274
    // linux/osx phantomjs 1.9.8 = 989
    var pageSize = 1274
    // the size of the area you want to cut
    var cutDivHeight = 200
    var numberOfPages = Math.ceil(document.height / pageSize)

    // run debug to see the values
    console.log(numberOfPages * pageSize - document.height)

    // find out if the extra div fits to the last page space
    if (numberOfPages * pageSize - document.height < cutDivHeight) {
        numberOfPages++
    }

    // add the cut area
    var watermark = document.createElement('div'); 
    watermark.innerHTML = "CUT ME"
    watermark.style.top =  (numberOfPages * pageSize) - cutDivHeight 
    watermark.style.height = cutDivHeight + 'px'
    watermark.style.width = '100%'
    watermark.style['background-color'] = 'red'
    watermark.style.position = 'absolute'
    document.body.appendChild(watermark)
</script>
```

Demo here
https://playground.jsreport.net/studio/workspace/BJEMYu3bb/36

Comment: Your link works great but when I try it in my local Jsreport server, it doesn't work well: I created a new template called "footer", then I pasted the HTML code and then I click Run. Should I configure something else?

Comment: It should just work, no need to change more. You may only have to adapt the pageSize constant if you run on osx/linux instead of on the windows where playground runs.

Comment: Yes, I have jsreport installed in a Linux computer. I tried different sizes till it worked: If pageSize is 989 it seems to work. Is it ok or is there a JavaScript function to get the value?

Comment: I did update the answer to include your 989 for linux. I'm not aware of the function which would calculate it. We need to stick with this magic constant for the time being.

Answer (score 1):

i think that you can achieve the desired design customizing the phantomjs footer with a fixed size and custom html, and adding custom page margins.

you can see a live example here: https://playground.jsreport.net/studio/workspace/BJEMYu3bb/31

take a closer look at the template's phantom options and the logic inside the footer to only be printed in the last page, also i'm not sure that it is going to work when you have content that move to another page maybe there is some kind of workaround that you will need to apply to have everything in place, but anyway this is a start.

Comment: It is not a good practice to answer question with a link only, since links can stop working in the future.